# Understanding the network structure of a multiple timeseries fusion model

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, time-series, convolutional-neural-network

## Please don't mark this question as duplicated to

[Can I create a layer with multiple rnn cell ? [question about a paper]](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/85694/can-i-create-a-layer-with-multiple-rnn-cell-question-about-a-paper/85912#85912)

It has already been marked 2 times , I admit they do refer to a same paper, but are totally different questions , please look carefully ! Above question is also from me which already be solved by myself , why I need ask another same quesion I have solved ?

---

I want to implement this paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3269206.3271794

It has structure graph :
[image]

But I can't understand how to generate `Multiple Resolution Tensor R` .

I understand all the steps except the detail of **step 3**:

1. we have 3 time series when α, β ∈ {day : 1,week : 7} ,  so dr = 2

> we can generate dr*(dr +1)/2 unique time series with different configurations of {⟨α, β⟩|α ∈ α, β ∈ β, α ≥ β} to represent multiple periodic time series distributions, in which dr = min(|α |, |β|).

2. we need 3 gru/lstm to generate 3 hidden state with `ds` length
3. Generate Multiple Resolution Tensor R

> Inspired by these recent advances, we propose a convolutional fusion
> framework to summarize a multi-resolution tensor $ R ∈ R^{|α |× |β |×ds} $ into a conclusive representation. Here we use R to represent a
> collection of time-evolving patterns generated from multiple time
> resolutions. Namely, $ R_{i,j,1:ds} $ denotes a learned sequence
> pattern representation $ h_t^{αi, βj} $ at time t w.r.t. temporal
> resolution αi and interval resolution βj as described in Eq. 2. We
> further apply a mirror padding along the diagonal to complete the
> tensor. The generation process of R is shown in Figure 1.(b).

4. Apply CONV2D
5. Apply CONV2D
6. Apply FC

---

## The ambiguous part is step **3** ! :

1. For me,  $ R ∈ R^{|α |× |β |×ds} $  shape is  `[dr*(dr +1)/2, ds]` , so I have to add one dim to `[dr*(dr +1)/2, ds, 1]` to make it can be pass to conv2d , is this right ?
2. But the `Figure 1` write the `ds` (gru hidden state length) as channels ,  and it also draw the channels size has to be divide by `2`  in every conv2d layer .

**What is the correct way to generate `Multiple Resolution Tensor R` ?**

### PS

I wrote a dummy model, you could reuse this :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(1000,3)), columns=['Sales', 'SalesDiff7', 'SalesAggMean7'])

multi_inputs = []
multi_outputs = []
window_size = k


for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    ti = keras.Input(shape=(window_size, 1), name=f't{i}')
    tlstm = layers.LSTM(32)(ti)
    multi_inputs.append(ti)
    multi_outputs.append(tlstm)
    
r = tf.stack(multi_outputs, axis=-2) 
r = tf.expand_dims(r, -1)  
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16,
                       kernel_size=(2, 2), #padding='same',
                       activation='relu')(r)
conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=8,
                       kernel_size=(2, 2), #padding='same',
                       activation='relu')(conv1)
fc = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(conv1)
result = keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(fc)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create a layer with multiple rnn cell ? \[question about a paper\]](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/85694/can-i-create-a-layer-with-multiple-rnn-cell-question-about-a-paper)

Comment: @hH1sG0n3 I have used tensorflow functional api to achieve multile RNN(horizontally)